# Global variables set in GUI with no values - Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, global-variables

I created a GUI to set parameters and use those parameters in another m-File. I know that the variables created in GUI are in a different workspace from the input variables to the m-File. For that reason, I'm trying to use `global variables`, but not sucesfully: the variables goes to the m-File empty.

I have a GUI which has 3 edit boxes, that the user can set parameters (0 or 1), using this code (showing the code for only one edit box):

```
function density_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to density (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of density as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of density as a double
global density
density = str2double(get(hObject, 'String'));
global Variavel_1
assignin('base', 'Variavel_1', density);
```

The m-File are called from a GUI BUTTON, using this code:

```
function calculate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to calculate (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

test %m-File that uses variables set in GUI
```

And the m-File should use this `Variavel_1` and the others from the remaining editboxes in this code (test.m):

```
global Variavel_1
global Variavel_2
global sum    

Variavel_1
Variavel_2
sum = Variavel_1 + Variavel_2
```

But all I have is all those variables empty! 
(I know I can put this code inside the GUI code, but that's not the real propouse because this simple m-File to sum will be much more complex, so I need the variables to go to a m-File).

```
Variavel_1 = []

Variavel_2 = []

Sum = []
```

Can anyone understand why the global variables fails?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In auto generated `OpeningFcn` callback, if you're using GUIDE
You can define variables/fields in `handle` structure.

This is initialization part. The data used by this can be shared across all widgets on the GUI.

So, in this callback, for `variable_1`,`variable_2`, `sum`, etc. you can have something like following:

```
handles.variable_1 = 1;
handles.variable_1 = 2;
handles.sum = handles.variable_1 + handles.variable_1 = 1;

% At end update handles structure
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

In other callback, say your `Button` or `Edit`  callback

you can update these values as normal like following

```
handles.variable_1 = 12;
handles.variable_1 = 23;
handles.sum = handles.variable_1 + handles.variable_1 = 1;

% Now, at end of callback save the change you made to the structure
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

To verify these values type `handles` at command window.

Ref :***[Store or retrieve GUI data](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)*** for more details.

To use these variables from GUI to other script simple assign them in workspace
like `assignin('base','variable_1',handles.variable_1);` ,etc  in any of the callback where `variable_1` is getting updated.

Then, in your m-script you can directly use these variables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know I can define the sum expression inside the GUI code, but that's not the real propouse. I'm sorry for not having made it clear. 
I have to pass those variables to the m-File, because the m-File will be much more complex than that.

Comment: @Luiz which `m-file` ? A `m-file` other than that of GUI itself ?
GUI code, the `callbacks` will be in `m-file` and its design will be saved in a `.fig` file
Have you created any other `m-file` by your own, other than that generated from `GUIDE` ?

Comment: Yes, the m-File is the one named "test" in my program, the one which makes the sum of the variables. 
So, the GUI pushbutton calls this "test.m" as shown above!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm already using `assignin()`, just forgot to copy that line to the question. But I use in a different way, so, I'll try this way and let you know.

Comment: Just tested and got the SAME RESULT, the variables are created, but they cannot acess the value by the m-File, resulting in an empty value

Comment: @Luiz will it be possible for you to show me your gui m-file and other `test.m`, or tell me how are you using them, it works

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just define your `test` function (saved in "test.m") as:

```
function sum = test(x, y)
sum = x + y;
```

And then call your `test` function from your `calculate_CallBack` function using:

```
sum = test(Variavel_1, Variavel_2);
```

Admittedly, I am not well versed in GUI programming in MATLAB, so there may be some really obvious reason for which you cannot do this, but this avoids using global variables, which often makes for cleaner code.